# Почему не могу сделать PUSH из SublimeText3?

Tags: linux, git, sublime-text

в sublime text 3 установил плагин Git.
не могу сделать push изменений.

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>       fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.
>       Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
>       и репозиторий существует.

ssh используется и из консоли все нормально пушится.

```
git push origin dev
Everything up-to-date
```

владелец папки проекта мой юзер, права 755.

на домашнем пк (ос вин7) все прекрасно работает.

в чем проблема? OS kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Попробуйте это: https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/525

Comment: А здесь прямо ваше сообщение об ошибке и отмеченный галочкой ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656642/sublime-text-3-git-cant-push

Comment: @Lenald, я же написал что ssh используется. проблема не в нем.

Comment: @Lenald, самое интересное что vscode без настройки прекрасно пушит все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не работает пуш из st3 из-за того что я запускаю его как рут, а ssh привязан к юзеру.

если запускать st3 как юзер то все работает.

при генерации ключа он записывается как ключ для юзера, а не для рута.